# Can I check whether a List contains an object that has fields with a certain value in java?

Tags: java, collections

I am trying to remove duplicate data from List with specific attribute of an object.

Comment: Yes.  But if you want a specific answer then pose a specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better option might be to implement `equals` and `hashCode` if the identity and equality for this particular type is based on the values of these fields that you are worried about.

That way you can build a set of these objects, which by definition won't contain duplicate instances.

If that's not possible (for example, if you don't have access to the source of this class), you can use [`anyMatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) with a predicate (only works in Java 8):

```
return list.stream().anyMatch(element -> element.getField().equals(someValue));
```

If you care about more fields, you can include them in the predicate as well.

In Java <= 7 you will have to iterate over the values:

```
boolean contains = false;
Iterator<MyObject> = list.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext() && !contains) {
    contains = iterator.next().getField().equals(someValue);
}

return contains;
```

Answer (score 0):

Overwrite equals(Object obj) method of your class. Cast obj to yoir class and check your certain filed(s).

Then insert all to a Set. There wont be any duplicates on set collection.